# What are the Feynman diagrams for neutrino oscillations?

Tags: mass, feynman-diagrams, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model, weak-interaction

Which Feynman diagrams are at the basis of neutrino oscillations? I find no clear explanation via Google.

Comment: I would guess it would be like the diagram for a Dirac mass; simply a vertex with one kind of neutrino coming in and another coming out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are none, and the question isn't really even sensible.

Neutrino oscillation is not mediated by force carrying particles any more than any other change of quantum basis is.

This is similar to asking *"What are the Feynman diagrams for the uncertainty principle?"*. In both cases we're talking about what happens when you treat a single quantum system in terms of observable $\hat{A}$, then in terms of observable $\hat{B}$ and then in terms of observable $\hat{A}$ again when $[\hat{A},\hat{B}] \ne 0$.